# Editing a Excel cell while loading taskpane app causes a error (5004)

Tags: office-js

I am currently experiencing a error, when I edit a cell while the excel task pane app loads. It returns a 5004 error code, which is "Invalid API call in the current context".

I manage to replicate this bug with the following code using the API Tutorial (Taskpane) app:

```
function displayAllBindingNames() {
Office.context.document.bindings.getAllAsync(function (asyncResult) {
    if (asyncResult.status !== Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {    
        console.log('failed!');
    }
    });
}

var interval = setInterval(displayAllBindingNames, 500);
setTimeout(function() {
clearInterval(interval);
}, 3000);
```

I need some help please, to find a solution to this bug.

Answer (score 2):

The error message could be clearer (and we actually have a work item to address this) -- but the behavior itself is a known and behavior.  Excel desktop is unfortunately unable to perform nearly all operations when in cell-editing mode: not just Office.js API operations, but also nearly all VBA/VSTO/COM API operations, or even UI functions (you'll notice that the ribbon goes disabled for almost all the features).

If you have suggestions for what we can do better given this constraint, I would be very interested to hear the alternatives!

Comment: Is it possible to leave the cell-editing mode via office.js?

Comment: @ndee, I have left the Office Extensibility space over a year ago. I recommend you ask (or search for) a separate question on this topic, tagged with "office-js". Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you Michael for this information - especial that it is not your focus anymore!
I found another question on this feature: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64238680/programmatically-remove-excel-cell-edit-mode?r=SearchResults&s=1|167.6274